# Check if DataRow exists by column name in c#?

Tags: c#, null, datarow

I want to do something like this:

```
   private User PopulateUsersList(DataRow row)
        {
            Users user = new Users();
            user.Id = int.Parse(row["US_ID"].ToString());
            if (row["US_OTHERFRIEND"] != null)
            {
                user.OtherFriend = row["US_OTHERFRIEND"].ToString();
            }
            return user;
        }
```

However, I get an error saying `US_OTHERFRIEND` does not belong to the table.
I want to simply check if it is not null, then set the value.

Isn't there a way to do this?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You should try

```
if (row.Table.Columns.Contains("US_OTHERFRIEND"))
```

I don't believe that row has a columns property itself.

Comment: I checked at the table level if (dt.Columns.Contains("US_OTHERFRIEND"))

Comment: Shorter version:
if (row.HasColumnValue("US_OTHERFRIEND"))

Comment: please show code that is case insensitive.

Comment: @crazyTech.. it is already case insensitive.

Answer (score 23):

```
if (drMyRow.Table.Columns["ColNameToCheck"] != null)
{
   doSomethingUseful;
{
else { return; }
```

Although the DataRow does not have a Columns property, it does have a Table that the column can be checked for.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the DataColumnCollection of Your datatable to check if the column is in the collection.

Something like:

```
DataColumnCollection Columns = dtItems.Columns;

if (Columns.Contains(ColNameToCheck))
{
  row["ColNameToCheck"] = "Checked";
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use

```
try {
   user.OtherFriend = row["US_OTHERFRIEND"].ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // do something if you want 
}
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, catching exceptions is expensive.

Comment: This is not a good practice.

Answer (score -8):

```
if (row.Columns.Contains("US_OTHERFRIEND"))
```

Comment: @Big Endian, DataRow doesn't have Columns property.

Comment: this doesn't work... DataRow row does not have Columns property.